# Adding data to TableView in another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a TableView which is HomeViewController
I also have another View which is NewViewController

In HomeViewController I can add items to the plist such as "Book Title" key by doing:

```
NSString *bookTitle;

self.books addObject:bookTitle
```

then a button is clicked to push to NewViewController where there is a text field. When the save button is clicked I need the text for the textField to be added to the table view "Book text" key in the plist

But I cannot do self.books in this class so how can I add to the tableview  thats in HomeViewController from NewViewController

Comment: Can you paste your code what you have tried so far??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a delegate method in NewViewController that is called when the button is clicked, passing the textField content to the HomeViewController. The HomeViewController implements the delegate method and can then update the books collection as appropriate. E.g.:

NewViewController.h

```
// Define the delegate method(s)
@protocol NewViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)addedTitle:(NSString *)text;

@end

@interface NewViewController : UIViewController

// Declare the delegate property
@property (nonatomic, weak)id <NewViewControllerDelegate>delegate;

// other declarations...

@end
```

NewViewController.m

```
#import "NewViewController.h"

@interface NewViewController ()

@end

@implementation NewViewController

// other implementation code...

-(IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender{
    [self.delegate addedTitle:textField.text];
}

@end
```

HomeViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NewViewController.h"

// Note <NewViewControllerDelegate> on next line
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <NewViewControllerDelegate>

// other declaration code...

@end
```

HomeViewController.m

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    myNewViewController.delegate = self;
}

// other implementation code...

#pragma mark - NewViewController delegate methods
// Implements the delegate callback
-(void)addedTitle:(NSString *)title{
    [self.books addObject:title];
}

@end
```

Comment: Hi, I am quite new to this, can you show some code or anything to aid me, thanks.

Comment: Thanks alot! ill have a crack at it now

Comment: Just come accross a problem actually, in the HomeViewController.m "title" contains nothing when I NSLog it

Comment: If you `NSLog` `textView.text` in the `buttonTapped` method in `NewViewController`, what do you get?

Comment: i think its due to the fact that self.delegate is null

Comment: If `self.delegate` is `nil`, the delegate method is not called and no error/exception occurs. I have updated the above to include setting the delegate in `HomeViewController` in the `viewDidLoad` method and also fixed a typo (was delgate, is delegate).